# Initial selected value for angularjs select from existing object

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to set the initial selected value of a select by using a value from an existing object. Lets say myObject has a initial status of Inactive. I want the select initial value to be set as Inactive. How can I go about doing that?

My select looks like:

```
<select data-ng-options="status for status in statusOptions" data-ng-model="myObject.Status"/>
```

In my controller i have this variable:

```
$scope.statusOptions = ["Active", "Inactive"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defaulting the value of Status to Inactive will cause it to be selected by default.

```
angular.module('main', []).controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myObject = {
        Status: 'Inactive'
    };
    $scope.statusOptions = ["Active", "Inactive"];
});
```

Also select is not a self closing tag.

```
  <select data-ng-options="status for status in statusOptions" data-ng-model="myObject.Status">
  </select>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/YM8u3/)

Comment: This answered the question I asked, but turns out my problem was just case sensitivity.

Comment: @dburgener how did u handle case sensitivity?

Comment: @RashmiPandit, I just fixed my code to be the same casing.

Comment: @dburgener does that mean if the values differ in case by any chance, the code won't work?